# How do I get a ListBox to display all info for an "ID" from a Textbox (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project where I want to display all of the incident information (from Database) for a Customer (which I get from a textbox/ user input).

I'm struggling to fill the ListBox and am not sure that I have the right idea so far for using the "RowFilter" function.

```
public partial class CustomerSurvey : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Incident incidentInformation;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnGet_Incidents(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        incidentInformation = this.GetInfoForSelectedCustomerID();
    }

    private Incident GetInfoForSelectedCustomerID()
    {
        //get row from AccessDataSource based on value in dropdownlist
        DataView customersTable = (DataView)
            SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        customersTable.RowFilter =
            "CustomerID = '" + txtCustomerID_ForIncidents + "'";
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)customersTable[0];

        //create a new product object and load with data from row
        Incident i = new Incident();

        i.IncidentID = (int)row["IncidentID"];
        i.CustomerID = (int)row["CustomerID"];
        i.ProductCode = row["ProductCode"].ToString();
        i.TechID = (int)row["TechID"];
        i.DateOpened = (DateTime)row["DateOpened"];
        i.DateClosed = (DateTime)row["DateClosed"];
        i.Title = row["Title"].ToString();
        i.Description = row["Description"].ToString();

        return i;
    }

    private void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Incident incident = (Incident)Session["Reservation"];

        lstCustomers.Display
    }
```

As you can see above the function DisplayInfo is unfinished. This is because I don't know how to fill the ListBox.

Another thing that I am considering is that there might be multiple incidents to a customer and I am not sure that I have the right approach with the class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the data in the database based on the Textbox value in the ListBox? If so, you can refer to below code.
If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement.

Aspx,

```html
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>     
            CustomerId:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnGet_Incidents" />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ThreadDemoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerId], [Name], [Country] FROM [Customers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnGet_Incidents(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
    GetInfoForSelectedCustomerID();
}

private void GetInfoForSelectedCustomerID()
{

    //get row from AccessDataSource based on value in dropdownlist
    DataView customersTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    customersTable.RowFilter = "CustomerId = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)customersTable[0];

    ListBox1.Items.Add(row["CustomerId"].ToString());
    ListBox1.Items.Add(row["Name"].ToString());
    ListBox1.Items.Add(row["Country"].ToString());

}
```

The result,

[image]